# Get all interlinked questions

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, api, linked-questions

As an example, this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1371012/print-utf-8-from-c-console-application

has linked questions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1371012

however some of those questions have linked questions of their own. it is
possible to get a list of all the interlinked questions, perhaps with Stack
Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) or some API?

Comment: This is not possible in the API due multiple bugs in the API, including [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307314/pagination-has-no-effect-on-certain-api-routes).

Answer (score 3):

In [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) you can create a [recursive Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). That allows you to join the results of an anchor query with repeatably executed subqueries. You have to carefully select a stop criteria otherwise it will try to link virtually almost all questions from SO.

In the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/809967?PostId=1371012&Level=3) the parameter Level determines how many steps there are between your start post and its linked (grand-)children:

```sql
;with links as (
   -- anchor query
   select postid
        , level = 0
   from postlinks pl
   where pl.RelatedPostId = ##PostId:int?1371012##
   union all
   -- link the previous links
   -- with the next set of postlinks
   select  pl.postid
         , rl.level + 1
   from links rl
   inner join postlinks pl on pl.relatedpostid = rl.postid
   where pl.relatedPostid <> ##PostId:int?1371012##
   and rl.level < ##Level:int?1##
)

select distinct 
       postid as [Post Link]
from links
where postid <> ##PostId##
```

If you choose level too high you'll be greeted by an error message

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

or run out of time and resource, whatever comes first.

[image: result of SEDE query]

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to filter out the deleted posts that are still present in the PostLinks table.

Comment: Something is up with that query. [Merely adding an `order by` clause](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/810110) reduces the output from 35 to 29 questions.?.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles hmm, looks like the distinct isn't doing a distinct, until you order the results. Not sure if that is by design in sql server or a bug.

Comment: I thought that too, but your query *is* returning 35 unique post ids. (The API returns 33 and has some that SEDE doesn't (don't think age is a factor, either).)

Comment: This query is simply returning wrong results. 45533466 is listed, but that number is not found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1371012. nor is 1371012 found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/45533466

Comment: Steven, *that* result is valid; there are 2 degrees of separation between those questions: **1371012 -> 10882277 -> 45533466**.  So if you look on [10882277's link page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/10882277), you will see both 1371012 and 45533466.

Answer (score 1):

In the SEDE, the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/809743/get-linked-posts-by-postid) can help to get linked posts by passing the postid.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PostId AS [Post Link]
FROM PostLinks
WHERE RelatedPostId = '##PostId##'
```

---

In Stack Exchange API v2.2, [`questions/{ids}/linked`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions) can be used to be get the linked questions by the postids. This link will return the [linked questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=1371012&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to the mentioned postid

<sub>in your case the postid is : 1371012</sub>

Comment: that link only has 11 results, which is actually less than the link I posted - I think some type of recursion is needed here

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you need to use a recursion to loop through all the pages using the `has_more` value from the result of the API Call

Below is an example:

```js
async _fetch(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => {
        return res.json();
    });
}

async getLinkedQues(ids) {
    let myDetails = [];
    let hasMore = false;
    let page = 1;
    do {
        if (hasMore) {
            page += 1;
        }
        const { items, has_more } = await this._fetch(
           `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3`+
            `/questions/${ids}/linked`+
            `?page=${page}`+
            `&&site=stackoverflow`
        );
        myDetails = myDetails.concat(items);
        hasMore = has_more;
    } while (hasMore);
    return myDetails;
}
```