# Pagination doesn't work for certain API routes/functions

Tags: bug, api, related-questions, linked-questions, pagination

Trying to fetch a list of linked questions from **the API fails if there are more than 100 results**<sup>(Or whatever is set by `page_size`)</sup>.

This API call to the first page:
          [/2.2/questions/402283;2492077/linked?page=1&pagesize=3...](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions#page=1&pagesize=3&order=desc&sort=creation&ids=402283%3B2492077&filter=!-W2e9lsSBSBP7OvdT5zI&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

yields:

```
"items": [ {
    "creation_date": 1518175118,
    "question_id": 48704674,
    "title": "What exactly does UnicodeString store from library ICU and how to print this on Linux?"
  }, {
    "creation_date": 1517385425,
    "question_id": 48537194,
    "title": "Foreign Language in Strings C++"
  }, {
    "creation_date": 1516353394,
    "question_id": 48337650,
    "title": "Assertion failure in std::ispunct in a simple program"
  }
],
"has_more": true,
"quota_max": 10000,
"quota_remaining": 7954,
"page": 1,
"page_size": 3,
"total": 159
```

while this API call to the second page:
          [/2.2/questions/402283;2492077/linked?page=2&pagesize=3...](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions#page=2&pagesize=3&order=desc&sort=creation&ids=402283%3B2492077&filter=!-W2e9lsSBSBP7OvdT5zI&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

**erroneously yields the exact same thing**:

```
"items": [ {
    "creation_date": 1518175118,
    "question_id": 48704674,
    "title": "What exactly does UnicodeString store from library ICU and how to print this on Linux?"
  }, {
    "creation_date": 1517385425,
    "question_id": 48537194,
    "title": "Foreign Language in Strings C++"
  }, {
    "creation_date": 1516353394,
    "question_id": 48337650,
    "title": "Assertion failure in std::ispunct in a simple program"
  }
],
"has_more": true,
"quota_max": 10000,
"quota_remaining": 7953,
"page": 2,
"page_size": 3,
"total": 159
```

---

This holds true for every set of parameters I tried and **also applies to other API routes**, such as [`/questions/{ids}/related`<sup>Example</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions#page=3&pagesize=3&order=desc&sort=rank&ids=46862689%3B45533466%3B41810586%3B38941721%3B37078944%3B30197758%3B27871124%3B27670969%3B24500167%3B23727211%3B18904081%3B15964702%3B12495132%3B10932473%3B9230783%3B8390874%3B3780378%3B2492077%3B1660492%3B402283&filter=!-W2e9lsSBSBP7OvdT5zI&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

If a set of questions has more than 100 linked questions<sup>(the max page_size)</sup>, there seems to be no way to get the results from the API.

Comment: has there been any update on this?